# iOS 5 Devices Without armv7 Support

Tags: ios, ios5, armv7, armv6

Are there any iOS 5 Devices without armv7 support?

I'm deploying for iOS 5 and still build for armv6 too. I wonder whether I can drop this architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it - armv6 supports up to the iPhone 3G, armv7 is for all iPads and the iPhone 3G S and up.

Since iOS5 will only run on the 3G S upwards - I'd say that you can safely drop the armv6 architecture as long as you are only supporting iOS5 and upwards.

Answer (score 2):

All devices supported by iOS 5 support the armv7 instruction set.